# Excel matching cell value and date range

Tags: excel, date-range

i'm working on some data checking and faced problem to ease my checking. Hope anyone here can help me

I've two sheet of data

Sheet 1

1. John   01.10.2017  10.10.2017   A
2. Chloe  10.10.2017  10.10.2017   B
3. Jess   20.11.2017  22.11.2017   C
4. John   12.10.2017  13.10.2017   D

Sheet 2

1. Name  Date         Result
2. John  01.10.2017    A
3. John  11.10.2017    #N/A
4. Chloe 10.10.2017    B

I need a formula to cater on Sheet 2, result column.
If sheet 2 name with date fall/collision in btw sheet 1 date range, excel could help show the result
note that name on sheet 1 maybe repeated with different date range, but sheet 2 i wish to check the name whether conllision with sheet 1 data

Appreciate if anyone can help

Answer (score 0):

First you need to format your dates properly. Format them as date times etc.

Then in the sheet 2 results column have a function something like this:

```
=IF(AND(A1=Sheet1!A1, B1>=Sheet1!B1, B1<=Sheet1!C1),TRUE,FALSE)
```

This will return TRUE for John for instance.

You then extend this for the rest of your cases.

Comment: Thanks. but it couldnt help me identified the correct name involve. note that name on sheet 1 maybe repeated with different date range, but sheet 2 i wish to check the name whether conllision with sheet 1 data

Comment: Added another condition to check if names match as well... Now it should only match if Names match, and the date is between the two date cells